# Creation of client account in website - prestashop error 504

Tags: php, apache, server, timeout, prestashop

We encountered the following 504 time-out error when trying to create a new account within the web. We can place the data correctly, when clicking on save the page (submit the form) it is loading forever until this 504 error appears.

On the contrary, if we look at the administration in clients, the users are created properly. We are on version 1.7.8.3, we just recently upgraded from version 1.6 and the rest of the website seems to be working fine.

If we put the login information of the new user created, you can correctly access the web with your account despite the fact that the creation has thrown this error.

First I thought if it was a redirection error, but looking at the prestashop files everything seems to be correct, I have tried to activate the debug mode, it does not throw any error either, everything is correct. I honestly have no idea what could be going on.

The only error we have seen is this:

> 2022-03-03 18:39:23 UTC [apache][:warn] [pid number] [client ip]
> Timeout waiting for output from CGI script
> /home/folder/www/web/public_html/index.php, referer:
> https://www.web.es/inicio-sesion?create_account=1

Comment: I would check for third party modules that are involved in customer registration hook. Maybe some of them is doing some heavy operation or failed API call that is triggering a server timeout.

Answer (score 2):

we had the same problem, both for the registration and for the payment of the order (Error 504, same prestashop version). We have discovered that the problem came from the configuration of the email. By default the setting is:
/usr/sbin/sendmail
You have to configure the option:
SMTP

I hope this information will help you solve the problem! Best regards

Comment: Thank You Karina, I will check your answer.